# AVL tree rebalancing

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have a problem with function rebalance(node*) for AVL tree. This function worked well in most of examples but it fails in some cases, for instance when I'm trying to get the key of node->left->left when node->left == NULL.

```
TAVLStabla
void AVLStabloMapa<Tkljuca, Tvrijednosti>::rebalansiraj(Node* temp) {
    while(temp != 0) {
        updateHeight(temp);
        if(height(temp->l) >= 2 + height(temp->d)) {
            if(height(temp->l->l) >= height(temp->d->d))
                rightRot(temp);
            else {
                rightRot(temp->d);
                leftRot(temp);
            }
        }
        else if(height(temp->d) >= 2 + height(temp->l)) {
            if(height(temp->d->d) >= height(temp->d->l))
                leftRot(temp);
            else {
                rightRot(temp->d);
                leftRot(temp);
            }
        }
                temp = temp->r;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'll be difficult for us to help you debug that from just this, sorry. Can you point us at the rebalancing algorithm you're trying to implement? Maybe we can spot a mistake in the implementation from that.

Comment: The only point where you look up `temp->l->l` (assuming l=left and d=right?) is where you've just guaranteed that `height(temp->l)` is at least two (but actually that doesn't guarantee that l->l is not null, only that one of l->l and l->d are not null?). Could you have a mistake in your height function? If it's actually `temp->d->d` that's the problem then I can't see how you know that it's safe to access this in the fourth line of the method.

Comment: Indeed, debugger failed as temp->d->d (and yes, l == left, d == right). Height functions are pretty trivial tho.
int heigh(Node* temp) {
  if(temp == 0)
   return -1;
  return temp->h;
 }
 void updateHeight(Cvor* temp) {
  temp->h = dajMax(height(temp->l), height(temp->d)) + 1;
 }

Comment: @user3084657 why don't you `+1` on left height in dajMax?

Comment: Idea is that height of the node is equal to max(height(leftChild), height(rigthChilder)) + 1; There is lecture on MIT OCW explaining that.